# Informix - Combining date and time field

Tags: sql-server, informix

We receive data in this format from informix tables

```
Run Date        Run Time
2017-05-22        0
2017-05-22        100
2017-05-22        200
2017-05-22        300
2017-05-22        400
```

Expected Output:

```
2017-05-22 04:00
```

I want combine both to get the datetime, so that manipulations can be done. Please help.

Comment: Informix or SQL Server?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Expected output

Comment: edited the question

Comment: What does 'Run time' mean? You should add expected output for *each* row.

Comment: What types do the two columns have?  Are they strings?  Or is one a DATE or DATETIME and the other an INTEGER?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't identify the types of the columns for the run date and run time values.  However, the plausible types for run date are DATE, DATETIME YEAR TO DAY, and CHAR(10); the plausible types for run time are INTEGER and CHAR(4).  For this exercise, there's no difference between INTEGER and SMALLINT, or CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n), and you could (but shouldn't) use a DECIMAL for the run time.  A properly specified question would avoid these problems.

Fortunately, it doesn't matter much — the same basic SQL code handles all the variations above — though you might need to add more casts for some of the more outré type combinations.

This code assumes you have `DBDATE="Y4MD-"` or equivalent set in the environment; you have to make changes if you both use a DATE column and a different value for `$DBDATE`.

#### DATE plus INTEGER

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rd_rt_date_integer;
CREATE TABLE rd_rt_date_integer
(
    run_date    DATE NOT NULL,
    run_time    INTEGER NOT NULL
                CHECK (run_time >= 0 AND run_time < 2400 AND MOD(run_time, 100) < 60),
    PRIMARY KEY(run_date, run_time)
);

INSERT INTO rd_rt_date_integer VALUES('2017-05-22', 0);
INSERT INTO rd_rt_date_integer VALUES('2017-05-22', 100);
INSERT INTO rd_rt_date_integer VALUES('2017-05-22', 200);
INSERT INTO rd_rt_date_integer VALUES('2017-05-22', 300);
INSERT INTO rd_rt_date_integer VALUES('2017-05-22', 400);

SELECT run_date, run_time,
       EXTEND(run_date, YEAR TO MINUTE) +
       MOD(run_time, 100) UNITS MINUTE +
       (run_time / 100) UNITS HOUR AS run_date_time
  FROM rd_rt_date_integer;
```

**Example output**

```
run_date    run_time    run_date_time
DATE        INTEGER     DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE
2017-05-22  0           2017-05-22 00:00
2017-05-22  100         2017-05-22 01:00
2017-05-22  200         2017-05-22 02:00
2017-05-22  300         2017-05-22 03:00
2017-05-22  400         2017-05-22 04:00
```

#### CHAR plus CHAR

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rd_rt_char_char;
CREATE TABLE rd_rt_char_char
(
    run_date    CHAR(10) NOT NULL
                CHECK (run_date MATCHES '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'),
    run_time    CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(run_date, run_time)
);

INSERT INTO rd_rt_char_char VALUES('2017-05-22', '0');
INSERT INTO rd_rt_char_char VALUES('2017-05-22', '100');
INSERT INTO rd_rt_char_char VALUES('2017-05-22', '200');
INSERT INTO rd_rt_char_char VALUES('2017-05-22', '300');
INSERT INTO rd_rt_char_char VALUES('2017-05-22', '400');

SELECT run_date, run_time,
       EXTEND(run_date::DATE, YEAR TO MINUTE) +
       MOD(run_time, 100) UNITS MINUTE +
       (run_time / 100) UNITS HOUR AS run_date_time
  FROM rd_rt_char_char;
```

*Example output*

```
run_date    run_time    run_date_time
CHAR(10)    CHAR(4)     DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE
2017-05-22  0           2017-05-22 00:00
2017-05-22  100         2017-05-22 01:00
2017-05-22  200         2017-05-22 02:00
2017-05-22  300         2017-05-22 03:00
2017-05-22  400         2017-05-22 04:00
```

For the most part, Informix is very good about automatically converting between types — the need to cast to `DATE` here (it could be to `DATETIME YEAR TO DAY` instead) is necessary because the optimizer doesn't know which of the myriad `DATETIME` sub-types to use when considering `run_date` as a `DATETIME`.  (OK: so 'myriad' is an exaggeration.  There are 56 distinct `DATETIME` sub-types and 7 synonyms for some of those types.)

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Cte(RunDate,RunTime)
AS
(
SELECT '2017-05-22',0   UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-05-22',100 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-05-22',200 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-05-22',300 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-05-22',400
)

SELECT CONCAT( RunDate,' ',ISNULL(STUFF(Right('0' + CAST(RunTime AS VARCHAr(10)),6),3,LEn(RunTime),''),'00')+' : 00')Expected from Cte
```

Expected OutPut

```
2017-05-22 00 : 00
2017-05-22 01 : 00
2017-05-22 02 : 00
2017-05-22 03 : 00
2017-05-22 04 : 00
```

Comment: It's not clear that the spaces around the colon are wanted, though they're easily eliminated.  It also isn't entirely clear that the runtime is always on the hour (last two digits 00), though I grant you the example data certainly always has zeros (but if they're always zero, why bother with them at all?).